# Selecting Text Between Strings Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting, guid

Evening all,

Is there an easy way to select text between strings?

For example: I have a script that imports a .txt file. I would like to select all the string in between objectGUID: and userAccountControl.

```
countryCode: 0
badPasswordTime: 131823486788076442
lastLogon: 131824500819176115
pwdLastSet: 131377781146718190
objectGUID:: +i+FBf6NJUy+G+T6S52UUw==
userAccountControl: 66048
badPwdCount: 0
codePage: 0
```

In the example above the result would be: +i+FBf6NJUy+G+T6S52UUw==

Eventually I would turn this into a variable in which I can call upon later.
Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards & thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that content is a file:

```
(Select-String -Path /file.txt -Pattern '(?<=objectGUID:: ).+').Matches.Value
```

This solution uses a positive lookbehind so it's not included in the capture.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this regex: `objectGUID:: (.*)`

Refer to group one to get the text behind `objectGUID`

Answer (score 0):

Try select string if running in powershell

`PS C:\> Select-String -Path "*.txt" -Pattern "objectGUID"`

This command searches through all files with the .txt file name extension in the current directory and displays the lines in those files that include the string "objectGUID".

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**Regex :**

```
objectGUID::[ ](.*)userAccountControl
```

**Verify through regex 101 :**

[image]